# C++/lists/iterators. Confusion over the word "other" within "const Text_iterator& other"

Tags: c++, list, iterator, line

While trying to define "list" to understand how C++ lists work following Stroustrup's book PPP 2nd ed.
A word of unknown origin called "other" just appears, I presume word "other" is just the name of a class Text_iterator object but I don't quite understand its purpose. Is it trying to compare the whole text with another text to contemplate the possibility of having opened a different text?

```
class Text_iterator { // keep track of line and character position within a line
    list<Line>::iterator ln;
    Line::iterator pos;
public:
// start the iterator at line ll’s character position pp:
    Text_iterator(list<Line>::iterator ll, Line::iterator pp)
      :ln{ll}, pos{pp} { }
    char& operator*() { return *pos; }
    Text_iterator& operator++();
bool operator==(const Text_iterator& other) const
    { return ln==other.ln && pos==other.pos; }
bool operator!=(const Text_iterator& other) const
    { return !(*this==other); }
};
Text_iterator& Text_iterator::operator++()
{
    ++pos; // proceed to next character
    if (pos==(*ln).end()) {
        ++ln; // proceed to next line
        pos = (*ln).begin(); // bad if ln==line.end(); so make sure it isn’t
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe... indent your code?

Comment: it was indented, the selection and transform to code tool made it like that

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is the name of a parameter---V
bool operator==(const Text_iterator& other) const
{ return ln==other.ln && pos==other.pos; }
// And so it this -------------------V
bool operator!=(const Text_iterator& other) const
{ return !(*this==other); }
```

You can name you parameters as you like, as long as it doesn't collide with  language keyword and starts with a letter or underscore.

For instance, this is going to be just as good a parameter name as `other`:

```
bool operator==(const Text_iterator& anotherIterator) const
{ return ln==anotherIterator.ln && pos==anotherIterator.pos; }
```

And the method (actually the `==` operator) is meant to compare two `Text_iterator` against equality, that is: 'do they point to the same position in the text?'

[edited]

The

```
bool operator!=(const Text_iterator& other) const
{ return !(*this==other); }
```

Is just the opposite of `operator ==`, so it is meant to answer to the question if 'do the two iterators point to different position in the a text?'. As it's simply a negation, it is quickest and safest to the implemented by just calling the `operator ==` and negate the result.

("Just in case" note): as for `*this` - you will need to understand the difference between `this` (which is a pointer) and `*this` which is a reference. This matter is fundamental for your progress in C++, so do it sooner rather than later.

Comment: what about this part? :S
                return !(*this==other)

Comment: @Kenzo added the explanation

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in what the functions are doing.  I assume you mean the 'other' parameter in the following functions:

```
bool operator==(const Text_iterator& other) const
```

and

```
bool operator!=(const Text_iterator& other) const
```

These are operator overloads for the equality and inequality operators. e.g.

```
my_object == other_object
my_object != other_object
```

So the 'other' is the 'other_object' in the comparison.